# How to make clicking on a link to goal using global site tag (gtag.js) events?

Tags: html, events, google-analytics, web-deployment

How to make clicking on a link to goal using global site tag (gtag.js) events ?

```
<a onClick=" gtag('event', 'GooglePlayDownload', { eventCategory: 'download', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'cafeBazar', eventValue: 1} );" href="https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.zamanak.zaer/?l=fa" class="btn btn-primary inverse scrollpoint sp-effect2">hy
```

why the above code dosen't work ?

Comment: read gtag events [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: I'm at the exact same point, using snake-case parameters. Chrome debug network tab shows zero communication with Google.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your parameters may be incorrect. You are using camel case while the docs state to use snake case.

Haven't tried this. Just may be a possibility.

Give this a try:

```
<a onclick="gtag('event', 'GooglePlayDownload', { event_category: 'download', event_action: 'click', event_label: 'cafeBazar', event_value: 1} );" href="https://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.zamanak.zaer/?l=fa" class="btn btn-primary inverse scrollpoint sp-effect2">Click Here</a>
```

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events for more details.